# Detecting a overlap in Nodes due to the object being squished

Tags: ios, swift2, skspritenode

**I'm looking for a way to test whether or not a node has been squished in between the side of the screen and a moving wall (Like a trash compactor).**

Visually, there is a square on the right side of the screen, and then a vertical rectangle is pushing it toward the left side of the screen.

Both my wall and player nodes have physics bodies, and the wall is moving in on the player at a constant rate. Obviously at a certain point the wall then overlaps the player because there is no more room for the wall to push the player. Is there a way to detect an overlap between nodes?

I've tried using this:
(The walls are squishing the player on the LEFT side of the screen)

```
if (playerNode.position.x + playerNode.size.width/2 > wallNode.position.x-wallNode.size.width)
{
//Do whatever
}
```

But this works very finicky, and I'd rather use something built into the physics engine if there is one
Thanks!

Comment: You should update your question to show an effort in solving the issue and for the sake of providing more context. See [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Questions like this are often downvoted. About problem itself... Yeah, you could probably check the position of a moving wall and based on that check for "contact". Or you could make physics bodies for both wall and a node and detect contact in that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright well I've found a solution to what I was doing -

If you use :

```
if ((playerNode.intersectsNode(wallNode) != nil)
{
//Do whatever
}
```

You get the exact result I was looking for. The player and the wall still collide normally but if the player is crushed into the wall this action is called. I simply put this if-then into the method:

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
}
```